# CNN for images with different channel sizes

Tags: machine-learning, convolution

Assuming the channels of an image have different sizes.
E.g.: red: 128x128, blue: 128x128, green: 256x256

Is it better to resize the green channel to a lower size, or would It be better to add a conv layer for the green channel to reduce the size?

I couldn't find a paper but would appreciate it if you could refer to one.